# Is this query still SARGable with two different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select productname, warehouseid, needsrefill
from tableA
where stockDate > '1/5/2011' and salesDate >= '2/5/2011'
```

If stockDate and salesDate both have indexes, this query will still be SARGable ...right?

Comment: From googling, it seems like that SARGable = Don't use functions.

Comment: @TimothyChoi That's an oversimplification. You can use functions so long as an _index_ uses the same function.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of.

It can't perform a simple seek that evaluates both predicates at once.

It can do a range seek on indexes with a leading column of either `stockDate` or `salesDate` with a residual predicate on the other column.

So assuming an index on `stockDate, salesDate` this can be used for a range seek on `stockDate > '1/5/2011'` but it will still need to evaluate all matching rows in that range to see if they meet the `salesDate` criteria.

Or it can do a range seek on two separate indexes with leading columns `stockDate` and `salesDate` then perform an index intersection (join both results) to get rows matching the `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

They are SARGable, but this not guarantees your indexes will be used. Check your execution plan to see if any index is used. This depends on number of rows in your table, on index fragmentation, statistics, etc